# The most efficient way to guess the number in range of x?

Tags: theory

I have a task where I need to guess the number in range. For example, lets say n is in range of 1 … 10^8, what is the most efficient algorithm to guess the number?

Comment: Homework: Look up and read about binary search. Consider how it works. Try it. Try to adapt it to improve it. Look up other search algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the guessing game as an example to use the Divide and Conquer Algorithm by halfing our possible number of guesses. To play the guessing, a person (player A) will choose a random numer from n to m, another person (player B) will have to guess player A's number in "x" turns. Player A will assist player B by telling player B if the number they guessed is higher than or lower than player A's randomly chosen number. The Divide and Conquer Algoritm will tell you if it is possible to guess player A's number in the given amount of turns x, and will tell the maximum amount of tries or guesses you will need in order to guess there number correctly.

using Divide and Conquer Algorithm:
Let's look at the guessing game example from before, but this time we will use the Divide and Conquer Algorithm to solve it

Player A: I am thinking of a number from 1 to 100, can you guess my number within 6 turns ?

Player B: Sure and in 6 turns or less, is your number 100/2 = 50 ?

Player A: Nope guess a higher number.

Player B: Okay, is your number (100 + 50) / 2 = 75 ?

Player A: Nope, guess a higher number.

Player B: Okay is your number round up (100 +75)/2 = 88?

Player A: Yes, congratulations you guessed my number in 3 turns you
win!